# "Vector erase iterator out of range" in C++

Tags: c++, vector

In this C++ code I try to erase element from the end of the vector but the program stops and I receive the message: `Expression: vector erase iterator outside range.`

What is the problem? 
After all is by this code the vector a vector of pointers or the way I pass them in push_back inserts only a copy of pointer?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<Player*> allPlayers;
    allPlayers = createPlayers();

    int numPlayers;

    cout<<"Vector size: "<<allPlayers.size();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"How many players are involved in the game(1-4)?\n";
    cin>>numPlayers;
    cout<<endl;
    allPlayers.erase(allPlayers.end());

    return 0;
}


vector<Player*> createPlayers(){

    Player *Player1 = new Player(1,1500);
    Player *Player2 = new Player(2,1500);
    Player *Player3 = new Player(3,1500);
    Player *Player4 = new Player(4,1500);


    vector<Player*> allPlayers;
    allPlayers.push_back(Player1);
    allPlayers.push_back(Player2);
    allPlayers.push_back(Player3);
    allPlayers.push_back(Player4);


    return allPlayers;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? The `vector<Player*>` seems to do nothing but cause memory leaks and undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your code (even if not bugged) has a memory leak. You have a vector of pointers but you don't attempt to free the memory that the pointers point to. This will not happen automatically. Code will be much easier for you if you have a vector of Players not a vector of pointers to Players.

Comment: So you say if I understand it that I should delete the pointers and not merely the elements of the vector?

Comment: Yes, either that, or don't use pointers. Not using pointers is the better solution as you won't have to delete anything. Using pointers is much more complicated.

Comment: @arjacsoh There's a reason the word "problem" isn't permitted in question titles. Please don't work around this by using "Ploblem" instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.end()` returns the iterator ***one past the last element***. That's why you're getting that error. You want the iterator to point to the last element. Not one-past the last element.

So try changing the line to:

```
allPlayers.erase(allPlayers.end() - 1);
```

And make sure that you properly handle the case where vector is empty.

---

Alternatively you could use `.pop_back()`, but in either case, you're gonna want to deal with the memory leaks as well as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: In other words `allPlayers.erase(allPlayers.end() - 1);` does what you want.

Comment: Or even simpler would be `allPlayers.pop_back();`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pop_back` member function. As said already, end does not give you the iterator for the last element but one past the last element.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back

Why do you want to create pointers of `Player`?

Modify the code as follows,

In main,

```
vector<Player> allPlayers;
createPlayers(allPlayers);
```

In createPlayers function:

```
void createPlayers(vector<Player>& allPlayers)
{
    Player Player1(1,1500);
    Player Player2(2,1500);
    allPlayers.push_back(Player1);
    allPlayers.push_back(Player2);
    return;
}
```