# Why is my use of static vectors not working?

Tags: c++

I am tryng to create an abstract base class that has a static vector that manages all instances of the class.

This is a simplified version of it:

```
//In Base.h:

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    ~Base();    

    static void doSomethingToAllInstances();
private:
    static std::vector<Base*> allInstances_;
};

//In Base.cpp:

#include "Base.h"

std::vector<Base*> Base::allInstances_;

Base::Base()
{
    allInstances_.push_back(this);
}

Base::~Base()
{
    auto it = std::find(allInstances_.begin(), allInstances_.end(), this);
    int index = std::distance(allInstances_.begin(), it);
    allInstances_.erase(allInstances_.begin() + index);
}
```

This code works until I try to work with vectors of types derived from this class. If I do that the program crashes and tells me that I'm trying to erase an iterator outside the range of the vector.

Is the problem already apparent, or is more information needed to determine it?

Comment: Don't show code that works - show code that doesn't work, that's where the problem is. Prepare a [mcve]

Comment: Note that `allInstances_.begin() + index` is just `it`.

Comment: The solution is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276901/vector-erase-iterator-out-of-range-in-c, the problem is with limits of the vector and not because of the derived class I believe!

Comment: This looks to me like a failure to obey [the rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Any instance created using the copy constructor won't be in the vector.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Of course! I feel like an idiot now. Thanks!

Comment: You are not accounting for the possibility of `std::find()` returning `allInstances_.end()`, which will throw off the calculation of the `index`.  Which you don't need anyway, since you can pass the iterator returned by `std::find()` to `allInstances_.erase()`.  Or, just use `std::remove(allInstances_.begin(), allInstances_.end(), this)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau S/he doesn't need to account for that, since all instances are supposed to be in the vector.

Comment: @user253751 Sure, once a proper copy constructor and move constructor are implemented. Then the destructor can become simply `allInstances_.erase(std::find(allInstances_.begin(), allInstances_.end(), this));`, or even `std::erase(allInstances_, this);` in C++20